# Destroy session codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, web

i used session in my code. when i tried to logout it's working. but when i klick back, the program still can reach the admin page again. i don't know why. i think it has been destroyed. when the admin page was refresh, session works. the program back in to homepage. the point is i have to refresh first to make my session work out.

this is my code.

the controller for login :

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller{
 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_user'); //memasukkan file model m_login.php ke dalam controller
    }
    function index()
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('isLogin'); //mengabil dari session apakah sudah login atau belum
        if($session == FALSE) //jika session false maka akan menampilkan halaman login
        {
            $this->load->view('home/index_home');
        }else //jika session true maka di redirect ke halaman dashboard
        {
            redirect('dashboard/index');
        }
    }
 
    function do_login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post("uname");
        $password = $this->input->post("pass");
        
        $cek = $this->model_user->cek_user($username,md5($password)); //melakukan persamaan data dengan database
        if(count($cek) == 1){ //cek data berdasarkan username & pass
            foreach ($cek as $cek) {
                $level = $cek['level']; //mengambil data(level/hak akses) dari database
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                'isLogin'   => TRUE, //set data telah login
                'uname'   => $username, //set session username
                'lvl'      => $level, //set session hak akses
            ));
                
            redirect('dashboard/index','refresh');  //redirect ke halaman dashboard
        }else{ //jika data tidak ada yng sama dengan database
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal Login!')</script>";
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }
        
    }

}
```

the controller for dashboard :

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->auth->cek_auth(); 
  
 }
 
 public function ceklogin(){
  $session = $this->session->userdata('isLogin');
     if($session == FALSE)
     {
        $this->load->view('home/index_home');
     }
 }
 
 public function index()
 {
  $this->ceklogin();
  
  $stat = $this->session->userdata('lvl');
  
  if($stat=='admin'){
   $this->load->view('admin/home/index_admin',$data); 
  }else{ 
   $this->load->view('member/home/index_member',$data);
  }
  
 }

public function logout()
 {
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  
  redirect('home','refresh');
 }
}
```

The auth in the folder libraries:

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth {
    public function cek_auth()
 {
  $this->ci =& get_instance();
  $this->sesi  = $this->ci->session->userdata('isLogin');
  $this->hak = $this->ci->session->userdata('stat');
  if($this->sesi != TRUE){
   redirect('home','refresh');
   exit();
  }
  
 }
 public function hak_akses($kecuali="")
 { 
     if($this->hak==$kecuali){ 
      echo "<script>alert('Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini!');</script>";
      redirect('dashboard/index');
     }elseif ($this->hak=="") {
      echo "<script>alert('Anda belum login!');</script>";
      redirect('home');
     }else{

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: what u get when u var_dump($this->sesi) of cek_auth ?

Comment: what version of Codeigniter you use?

Comment: Nice, let's take it from the very begining: Session class on CI v2 does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data. It requires (1) an _encryption key_ in your config file and (2) _Mcrypt extension_ installed. As I do not see in the your code any `$this->load->library('session')`, you have to (3) _autoload the session library_. Are (1), (2) and (3) ok in your system?

Comment: yup...i've already done what you said. but my problem not solved

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unset` to destroy session. this is the example :

```
public function logout(){
  foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
    redirect('home','refresh');
}
```

Comment: that is because session class on CI v2 does not utilize native php sessions

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is in your `Dashboard` Controler, `function ceklogin()`. When you destroy a session `$this->session->userdata('isLogin')` returns `NULL` (not false, [check CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)), so it passes the comparing `($session == FALSE)`.

Edit your `function ceklogin()` so that `$session = $this->session->userdata('isLogin')` compares both to `FALSE` and `NULL` ex.

```
public function ceklogin(){
    $session = $this->session->userdata('isLogin');
    if (($session == FALSE) || ($session == NULL))
    {
       $this->load->view('home/index_home');
    }
}
```

---

**A more analytical explanation of your case** (I think it will be useful)

While the user is on a session your code works fine.

After destroying the session and hit 'back' (calling some method of Dashboard Controller), `$session = $this->session->userdata('isLogin')` gets `NULL` so it passes the `($session == FALSE)` check.

When you refresh the page your session is reconstructed and `$this->session->userdata('isLogin')` gets `FALSE` value (so it does not pass the `($session == FALSE)` check.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in your logout function

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->library('session');      
$CI->session->sess_destroy();
```

this might solve your problem 
i suppose you are writing this code in your library file

Comment: do you mean like this? add one function logout?
 public function logout()
 { 
     $this->ci =& get_instance();
$this->ci->load->library('session');      
$this->ci->session->sess_destroy();
 }

Comment: so i have to call that function in the controller too?